# Facebook and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise

My rails app is now going to the facebook page and allowing a user to sign in but it's redirecting them back to the sign in page on my rails app.

When I check the server logs, there's a few errors:

---

I, [2014-04-17T14:47:35.459639 #95904]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2014-04-17T14:47:35.946870 #95904] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, :
{"error":{"message":"This IP can't make requests for that application.","type":"OAuthException","code":5}}
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML

I'm confused why it's not capturing the user and creating them and signing them in like my twitter app is. I can post my code if neccessary

Comment: It sounds like you've specified an IP address or addresses in the `Server IP Whitelist` in the Facebook app Settings -> Advanced config. and the request you've made is not originating from one of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thought I had to declare an IP address but guess not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it seems an IP address or addresses had been specified in the `Server IP Whitelist` in the Facebook app `Settings -> Advanced` config. and the request being made wasn't originating from one of them.

Specifying the IP addresses from which you make requests to Facebook is optional, but if you know the IP address(es) you'll be using and they don't change, then it's some nice extra security to be able to tell Facebook that you'll only ever send requests from those addresses.

Note there are other settings you can use to increase security - for example, the appsecret_proof parameter on API calls https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/ -- and omniauth-facebook adds this automatically as of 1.6.0, so you should just be able to turn that option on in the Facebook `Settings -> Advanced` config if you happen to be using that version of omniauth-facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem is that the Server IP Whitelist had an IP address registered, and when FB receives a request from any other IP address, it throws that error.
Delete the address [if any] so that your admin site looks like this:
[Facebook Admin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJfCo.png)